# Is there any way to invoke tabledata.list via JDBC?

Tags: google-bigquery

To avoid extra charging using BigQuery Magnitude Simba JDBC driver I'm looking for implementation of BQ API `tabledata.list` method in JDBC, is there any?

Comment: Please provide more details about your env, is on cloud, which products are you using? What exactly you want to do with [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) ? Can you provide use case?

Comment: We work with BigQuery via Magnitude Simba JDBC. To avoid extra costs we try to avoid `select * ` to retrieve table data. 

E.g. `SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 500` is the same as `SELECT * FROM x`. [So driver fetch the whole table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) for extra costs . 

So, we're [looking for any way to preview data](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14015) via JDBC API.

Comment: If you want to optimize cost, you could optimize query like mention in [Use query parameters to speed up frequently executed queries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices#query-parameters), or using built-in [date functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)?

Comment: I'd like to optimize and see first 500 rows of the table - that's it. 

I can't get why `LIMIT` is ignored and BigQuery retrieves all data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected in BigQuery. In [Controlling costs in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) guide you can find information:

> Applying a `LIMIT` clause to a `SELECT *` query does not affect the amount of data read. You are billed for reading all bytes in the entire table, and the query counts against your free tier quota.

In this guide you have also a best practice how to reduce costs like using `SELECT * EXCEPT` to reduce the number of columns or using clause `where` with partitioned table.

The closest thing which you are asking is to use [Sample data using preview options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#preview-data)

> In the API, use [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) to retrieve table data from a specified set of rows.

You can find some examples in [List tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-list-tables#bigquery_list_tables-java) or [Preview table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-browse-table#bigquery_browse_table-java) samples